# p5.js image in a buffer

Tags: buffer, p5.js

I am trying to load image "image.png" and place it in the preaviously created createGraphics() buffer.
However when I load the buffer in draw() the image is not there.
I am wondering if an image can be loaded into a buffer, and if so how ?

```
var buffer;
var image;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 800);
    image = loadImage("image.png");
    buffer = createGraphics(800, 800);
    buffer.background(255, 255, 0);
    buffer.image(image, 0, 0)
}

function draw() {
    image(buffer, 0, 0);
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not good to call your variable `image` as p5.js already has an `image()` function (which you use).
2. Use `preload()` to load the image. This ensures that the image is actually loaded before you try to load it in your buffer within `setup()`. See [here](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload) for more info on this.

A working example is given [here](https://editor.p5js.org/janmaltel/sketches/zSsjjUQOO). It uses the following p5 code.

```js
var buffer;
var img;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("p5im.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  
  buffer = createGraphics(400, 400);
  buffer.background(255, 255, 0);
  buffer.image(img, 0, 0)
}

function draw() {
  image(buffer, 0, 0);
}
```